# How to force HTTPS on all URL's except one directory /images using .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

I am using WordPress and we have one directory that is not a WordPress directory /images and we need this directory to be HTTP only everything else should be forced to HTTPS.

In the WordPress settings we have the domain set to HTTP

[image: WordPress settings]

and in the `.htaccess` file we have the below.

I can not seem to get this to work. Our host is cloudways if that helps any

```
# This file was updated by Duplicator on 2018-09-10 16:52:27. See .htaccess.orig for the original .htaccess file.
# Please note that other plugins and resources write to this file. If the time-stamp above is different
# than the current time-stamp on the file system then another resource has updated this file.
# Duplicator only writes to this file once during the install process while running the installer.php file.

#RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(images)
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(images)
#RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress



# MalCare WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
  Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END MalCare WAF
```

Comment: "not a wordpress directory /images" - When you say it's "not a WordPress directory", I assume it's not used by your WordPress site in any way? ie. None of your pages reference images in the `/images` subdirectory? Not sure why you are seemingly trying to redirect from HTTPS back to HTTP in two of the rules you've posted? I thought you want to force HTTPS, except for a specific subdirectory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the wordpress settings we have the domain set to http

If you are wanting to force HTTPS everywhere except for the one directory, which is "outside of WordPress" then the "WordPress Address" and "Site Address" in the WP dashboard should both be set to HTTPS, not HTTP.

> ```
> #RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
> #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(images)
> #RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
>
> #RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
> #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(images)
> #RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
> RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
> ```

In the root `.htaccess` file you can redirect to HTTPS *everywhere*, but make an exception to exclude further processing if the `/images/` directory (the one that should remain as HTTP) is requested.

For example:

```
# Prevent further processing if the "/images" directory is requested
RewriteRule ^images($|/) - [L]

# Redirect everything else to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
:
```

No need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive, since this already occurs later in the file (in the WP section).

Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing and test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues.

This assumes the SSL cert is installed on your application server and you aren't using a proxy/CDN/load balancer that might be managing the SSL connection.

---

**UPDATE:** Since the above is still resulting in a redirect-loop it's possible you are behind a proxy server of some kind (either CloudWays - your webhost - or perhaps Cloudflare) that is managing the SSL connection. Try the following instead for the second rule (HTTP to HTTPS redirection):

```
# Redirect everything else to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This gives me to many redirects

Comment: @GavinPedley Sorry, should have been `https://` (not `http://`) in the _substitution_ string! (Good reason for testing with 302s!) I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks still seems to be giving too many redirects on any URL other than the images folder.

Comment: Have you updated WordPress to HTTPS? (Otherwise, WP itself will redirect back to HTTP.) Are you behind a proxy / load balancer, using a CDN like Cloudflare (Flexible SSL)?

Comment: I'm on cloudways using their basic lets encrypt SSL. Not using their CDN. DNS is through cloudflare but not using any proxy with them just DNS only.

Comment: And you've updated WP to HTTPS? You're not using Cloudflare CDN?

Comment: Yes updated to HTTPS in WP

Comment: @GavinPedley I've updated my answer with an alternative. Clear cache, test with 302 etc.

Comment: @GavinPedley Ok, that's great! That would seem to suggest that you _are_ behind a reverse proxy server that is managing the SSL cert.